# Incorrect update statement in Slick 3.1.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following Slick action that updates all dates in year 2016 excluding Saturdays and Sundays

```
  val action = dates.filter( d => d.year === 2016 && 
            d.weekDay != "Sat" && d.weekDay != "Sun").map(x => (x.isHoliday)).update(0)
  Await.result(db.run(action), Duration.Inf).value
  val sql = action.statements.head
  println(sql)
```

Problem is that the update doesn't work as intended, the sql prints

```
update `dates` set `is_holiday` = ? where ((`dates`.`year` = 2016) and true) and true
```

when it should print

```
update `dates` set `is_holiday` = ? where `dates`.`year` = 2016 
        and `dates`.`week_day` != 'Sat' and `dates`.`week_day` != 'Sun'
```

What is wrong with this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are accidentally using the scala `!=` operator instead of the Slick `=!=` function.  Try this:

```
val action = dates.filter(d => d.year === 2016 && d.weekDay =!= "Sat" && d.weekDay =!= "Sun").map(x => (x.isHoliday)).update(0)
```

You could also try this:

```
val weekendDays = Set("Sat", "Sun")
val action = dates.filter(d => d.year === 2016 && !d.weekDay.inSet(weekendDays))
```